# Creating a bootable flash drive

Tags: boot, live-usb

I need to make a bootable Windows 8.1 flash drive and am trying to follow the instructions on this site "How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows". I am confused when I try following the 2nd screeshot "Click Browse and open the downloaded ISO file.
What ISO file is that and where do I download it from?  Any assistance would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Barry

Comment: Do you have `.iso` file that you want to use it and create a bootable flash drive ? also where are your links?

Comment: Do you want to put Windows 8 on the flash drive or are you running Windows 8?

Comment: The instructions are about creating it on Windows, with Ubuntu on it, not with Windows on it. The secons has nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

- Download the iso image from here: 
  http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso. It would be around 800MB
- Download unetbootin from the given link: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/
- When asks for iso location, point to the location where your download iso.
- Then click OK button, and wait it till it does it work, when it's done, you've bootable flash drive.

Comment: Why do you link to 12.04 instead of 14.04.1?